# Is it true that for $p_j^{\alpha_j-1}(p_{j}-1)>2(3^{k-1})$ for some $j$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq m)$ be primes such that $p_i < 2(3^{k-1})+1 $, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $a=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}$ for some $\alpha_i >0$. Let $a > 2 (3^k)$. Is it true that for $p_j^{\alpha_j-1}(p_{j}-1)>2(3^{k-1})$ for some $j$ ?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, why should there be such a $j$? There are tons of primes less than $2\cdot3^{k-1}$, and $a$ could be the product of all of them, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $p_i-1 <2(3^{k-1})$, hence there exist a real number $t>1$ such that $(p_i-1)t=2(3^{k-1})$. Now, let $p_i^{\alpha_i-1}>t$ 
then $p_i^{\alpha_i-1}(p_i-1)>t(p_i-1)=2(3^{k-1})$, hence the proposed inequality holds if $p_i^{\alpha_i-1}>t=2(3^{k-1})/(p_i-1)$. So for any $\alpha_i$ choosen to satisfy the last inequality, the proposed ineqaulity is automatically satisfied. Otherwise, the proposed inequality MAY NOT be satisfied, and so the result is, generally, inconclusive in that case